# Packages are not recognized in Perl

Tags: perl

I have created build script in search way it will place all project dependencies inside target folder. This target folder will be inside the project root directory. This target folder contains bin,lib folder. Inside lib folder all dependencies are there.

I have set path search as:

```
export PERL5LIB="$PWD/target/lib/perl5:$PWD/target/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux:$PWD/targer/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi"
```

When I build my project it is throwing following errors.

> > Can't locate Clone.pm in @INC (@INC contains: lib /home/smopuru/pigeon/target/lib/perl5 /home/smopuru/pigeon/target/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux /home/smopuru/pigeon/targer/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi lib /home/smopuru/pigeon/target/lib/perl5 /home/smopuru/pigeon/target/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux /home/smopuru/pigeon/targer/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi /home/smopuru/pigeon/target/lib/site_perl/5.14.2/x86_64-linux /home/smopuru/pigeon/target/lib/site_perl/5.14.2 /home/smopuru/pigeon/target/lib/5.14.2/x86_64-linux /home/smopuru/pigeon/target/lib/5.14.2 .) at lib/Pigeon/Compiler.pm line 29, <> line 1.
> >
> > Can't locate Mouse.pm in @INC (@INC contains: lib /home/smopuru/pigeon/target/lib/perl5 /home/smopuru/pigeon/target/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux /home/smopuru/pigeon/targer/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi lib /home/smopuru/pigeon/target/lib/perl5 /home/smopuru/pigeon/target/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux /home/smopuru/pigeon/targer/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi /home/smopuru/pigeon/target/lib/site_perl/5.14.2/x86_64-linux /home/smopuru/pigeon/target/lib/site_perl/5.14.2 /home/smopuru/pigeon/target/lib/5.14.2/x86_64-linux /home/smopuru/pigeon/target/lib/5.14.2 .) at lib/Pigeon/Compiler.pm line 29, <> line 1.

I am sure these two files are available. The commands that i used to search for:

```
find target/lib/ -name Clone.pm target/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/Clone.pm
find target/lib/ -name Mouse.pm target/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/Mouse.pm target/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/Test/Mouse.pm
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [@INC Perl- Can't locate Class/CSV.pm in @INC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11780324/inc-perl-cant-locate-class-csv-pm-in-inc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There's a typo in your `PERL5LIB` - you have "targer" instead of "target" on one of the paths.  That's the reason for the Clone.pm miss.
2. Mouse.pm is in `.../something/in/your/path/Test/` rather than `.../something/in/your/path` which means you either need to `use Test::Mouse;` in your script or move the Mouse.pm file up one directory in the filesystem.

Comment: Thanks for finding spelling mistake  now i am getting the following error               target/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/auto/version/vxs/vxs.so: undefined symbol: Perl_Gthr_key_ptr

Comment: You're trying to run compiled code on an incompatible version of perl (either a different platform or different perl version.) You can't do that. You'll either have to package a Perl interpreter with your distribution (check out [PAR::Packer](https://metacpan.org/module/PAR::Packer)) or use an automated build system to properly build your dependencies.